# Replying To email via Outlook in Python

Tags: python, email, outlook

I am trying to reply to emails with a keyword in the subject but I need to do it all through outlook. My current code works decently but it would be better if it could reply directly instead of creating a new message.

Hopefully this is the right place to ask this :)

```
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)    
    def check_mail():
        global message
        messages = inbox.Items
        message = messages.GetLast()
        if (message.subject.find('@Bot') != -1 and message.unread and whtlist.find(message.SenderName)!= -1 ):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    def Read_mail():
        global message
        global ACTIVE
        body_content = message.body
        print(bcolors.WARNING+'\n______________________________________________________________________\n'+bcolors.OKGREEN)
        print (body_content)
        print(bcolors.WARNING+'\n______________________________________________________________________\n'+bcolors.OKGREEN)
        for att in message.Attachments:
            break
        try:
            att.SaveAsFile(os.getcwd() + '\\new.xlsx')
            print(os.getcwd())
        except :
            print(bcolors.WARNING+'No Attachment Found'+bcolors.OKGREEN)
        message.unread=False
        Msg = o.CreateItem(0)
        Msg.To = message.SenderEmailAddress
        print(bcolors.FAIL+'Reply sent to: {}'.format(message.SenderEmailAddress+bcolors.OKGREEN))
        Msg.Subject = 'Autoreply'
        Msg.Body = 'I see you {}.\n\nTesting\n-Bot'.format(message.SenderName)
        Msg.Send()
```

Comment: I've found it easier to use the message.htmlbody, rather than message.body, especially for formatting.

Comment: Hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433633/reply-to-email-using-python-3-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `Items.GetLast` - it is not guaranteed to return the last received email. The Items collection is not sorted in any particular way unless you explicitly call `Items.Sort`. In your particular case, use `Items.Restrict` or `Items.Find/FindNext` to find the message based on your criteria (unread, subject contains a particular word, etc.).

To get a reply, call `MailItem.Reply` instead of `Application.CreateItem` - it will return the new `MailItem` object.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure I already tried "message.Reply()" but it works perfectly now :)