# How to reply to email object smtp mail

Tags: python, smtp, imap

I have a email object of an unread email. How do I reply to the email using smtp lib using the email object. I have refered to [Setting different reply-to message in Python email/smtplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938890/setting-different-reply-to-message-in-python-email-smtplib) link. Here they are using the email sender to reply to the email. I tried using the same method without adding a to address and only using `msg['reply-to']`, but was getting an error which is attached below. But when I use `msg['to']`  I was able to send the email to the sender but was not able to reply to the email.

ERROR:

`smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'None': (553, b'5.1.3 The recipient address <None> is not a valid RFC-5321 address. Learn\n5.1.3 more at\n5.1.3  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596 ij25-20020a170902ab5900b0016beceac426sm3191763plb.138 - gsmtp')}`

Comment: Why your images are the same?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add another image. Will rectify. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.merge`:

```
generated_file = pd.read_excel("generated_file.xlsx")
database = pd.read_excel('database.xlsx')

generated_file.merge(database, on='PRODUCT', how='left')
```

**OR** from your code, use `.isin`:

```
out = database[database["PRODUCT"].isin(result)]
```