# Reply to email python smtp

Tags: python, smtp, gmail

I am trying to write python code to reply to an email. I have manually checked in Gmail and understood that Gmail replies to an email using the same subject and uses the message uid. I am using Gmail, so I have referred to this link  ([Setting different reply-to message in Python email/smtplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938890/setting-different-reply-to-message-in-python-email-smtplib)) and implemented the same code. I am able to send the email but it does not send as an email reply. How do we implement if a@gmail.com wants to reply to an email sent from b@gmail.com? Could someone please share a snippet of code explaining the same?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938890/setting-different-reply-to-message-in-python-email-smtplib have you tried some of these solutions? using "reply-to" header?

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: @Alex-Bender, I have tried the same but it was not successful. I was receiving the email but not as an reply email.

Comment: @Dalm To, Could you be more specific on which part of the question I have to work on as to me the question seems clear.

Comment: @AlexBender There is no info in the python smtp email documentation about reply emails.

Comment: @Subinprasad try to search info on "gmail reply-to headers" query: it looks like there are some problems with reply-to headers